# PHP - Echoing a large JSON string doesn't output unless something else has already been echoed/printed, even with Content-Type set

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, echo

I've written a simple api which lets me get the data from my database in an organised way. www.example.com/api/get/all gives me all the data from one table in the database as an array, encodes it as json and then echos it. This is used by a file which is called as a CRON job every day and dumps it (and some other data) to a .js file which the website front-end uses.

Strangely, if I go to www.example.com/api/get/all it runs for about 2-3 minutes (there is a lot of data in that table) and then outputs nothing to the screen. However, if I add an echo to the function before it loops through all the data, I get the json encoded data string outputed to the screen. Has anybody come across this before? Is it a bug? Is there a workaround?

It seems very strange that it will only echo after there has been an echo/print.

Here is the parts of my api that are relevant:

```
// ENDPOINT people:
private function candidates()
{
    $response = new stdClass();

    // Fetch all users:
    if( $this->verb == 'all' )
    {
        // Get everyone from the DB:
        $sql = $this->_db->query( 'SELECT id FROM ff_candidates' );

        if( $sql )
        {
            $candidates = array();

            while( $obj = $sql->fetchObject() )
            {
                 // var_dump($obj);

                $candidate = new Candidate( $this->_db, $obj->id );

                $person = new stdClass();

                // Start the response:
                $person->id       = $candidate->get_id();
                $person->name     = utf8_encode($candidate->get_name());
                $person->gender   = $candidate->get_gender();

                $candidates[] = $person;
            }

            $this->_response( $candidates );
        }
        else
        {
            $response->success = false;
            $response->message = 'There was a problem fetching the candidate. Please try again.';
            $this->_response( $response, 500 );
        }
    }
}

// Send a response to the server:
private function _response( $response, $status = 200 )
{
    $verbose = $this->_requestStatus( $status );
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header( 'HTTP/1.1 '.$status.' '.$verbose );

    if( is_string($response) )
    {
        $data = new stdClass();
        $data->message = $response;
        $data->status  = $status;
        $data->title   = $verbose;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = $response;
    }

    $json = json_encode( $data );
    echo $json;
    exit();
}
```

EDIT:

_requestStatus() code:

```
private function _requestStatus( $code )
{
    $status = array(
        200 => 'OK',
        400 => 'Bad Request',
        401 => 'Unauthorized',
        402 => 'Payment Required',
        403 => 'Forbidden',
        404 => 'Not Found',
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        429 => 'Too Many Requests',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
        503 => 'Service Unavailable',
    );

    return ( $status[$code] ) ? $status[$code] : $status[500];
}
```

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($candidates)` after the `while` loop and update your question with the result?

Comment: Are you suppressing errors?

Comment: @MehdiBounya Thanks for the idea but nothing was outputted.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript No, error_reporting was default but now I've just ran it again with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` just in case but still nothing is showing in the error_log.

Comment: Now inside the `while` loop after declaring `$candidate` do a `var_dump($candidate)`

Comment: @MehdiBounya Yes, that works and causes the _response() output to fire too. But if I don't output anything else before _response() is called, I don't get the echoed data from _response(). Does that make sense? It seems strange to me. Is it because of the headers set in _response()? Because if I've done a var_dump/echoed something before _response() is called, the headers have been sent and can't be modified?

Comment: @MehdiBounya I just tried printing "" or something simple like "." before calling _response() to see if it was the headers issue but it's just outputting nothing again and I get a 500 error. If I look in the error_log, there is nothing in there.

Comment: Ok I'm from my phone, what does `_requestStatus` do? Can you remove `exit` and why is it there

Comment: @MehdiBounya It just holds the array of status codes and returns text based on the code. I've added that function as an edit in the original post.

Comment: @MehdiBounya Thank you for your help in trying to find the problem with me but I'm still at a loss. To fix it for now, I'm letting it var_dump($candidates) and then call _response() and then just str.split() on the output to ignore all the text var_dump() outputs. It's a crappy hack but it works at least.